# How to apply double filter in java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an Employee class having salary and department and a employee list.

```
static class Employee {
    private String department;
    private int salary;

    //getters
    getDeparment()
    getSalary()
}

List<Employee>
```

I need to find the number of departments with minimum 30 employees having paid minimum of 100 as salary.

So far I have got this which gives me number of employees per department. But I'm not sure how to apply the filters.

```
HashMap<String, Long> collect = employees
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, HashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the next step is to do a similar statement to collect the minimum salary of each department. Then try to combine the two together.

Comment: As for applying a filter, you should be able to add `.stream().filter()` to what you have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```java
Set<String> departments = employees.stream()
        .filter(employee -> employee.getSalary() >= 100)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, HashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() >= 30)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

You start by filtering out the employees that have a `salary` of less than 100. Then you group the employees by `department` and count the number of `employees` in the `department`. Finally, you need to filter out all departments that have less than 30 employees and map the final result to a `Set`.

Comment: This looks like the right direction by chaining more methods. However, I don't think this will do the "department having a paid minimum of 100 as salary". I read that as "get the lowest pay of all employees in each department. Then take any department that has at least 100 for that value."

Answer (score 1):

```
  HashMap<String, Long> collect = employees
                .stream()
                .filter(e-> e.getSalary() >= 100 && e.getDeparment().getEmployees().size >= 30)
```

I don't know your getters but you get the point. In the end just collect it to map

Comment: Updated my getters. I do not have get employees in the department which i have to derive from the employee list

Comment: how does your Department class look?

Comment: Looks like department is a String, there is no class.

Comment: Oh then use @João Dias answer I thought you had object there too